# Prevent Form from Clearing with Flask Inheritance

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

I have a form, which I would like to not get cleared out on submit (post).
I am using `<option selected="selected">{{ yourvalue }}</option>` to keep the value in the field before generating the other option values. The problem with this is then `yourvalue` is duplicated in the select box. I could remove `yourvalue` from the `list`, `numbers`, that goes into populating the options, but then things get out of order as the selected value appears at the top. Overall, this just seems like a clunky way to keep the selected value in the form on submit. What is the correct way to do this?

__init__py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test():
    numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template('body.html', yourvalue=request.form['number'], numbers=numbers)
    return render_template('form.html', numbers=numbers)

app.run()
```

form.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" >

    <select class="form-control" id="number" name="number" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>

        <option selected="selected">{{ yourvalue }}</option>
            {% for z in numbers %}
                <option value="{{ z }}">{{ z }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{%  block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

body.html

```
{% extends "form.html" %}
{%  block body %}
You chose {{ yourvalue }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misinterpreted your question initially. Could you change the HTML to something like this? Basically adding an Jinja If statement to see if the 'yourvalue' matches 'z' and if so, add "selected" to the option.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" >

    <select class="form-control" id="number" name="number" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>

            {% for z in numbers %}
                <option {% if yourvalue = z %}
                          selected
                         {% endif %}
                  value="{{ z }}">{{ z }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. This may be a bit more pythonic to use sessions instead of a variable, but it doesn't really help the issue with the html form that I'm asking about.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question. I just changed the whole answer!